Первая итерация в цикле for игнорирует условия наследования
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle

class MainStyle(ParagraphStyle):
    def __init__(self, size=10):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.name = 'my_style'
        self.defaults['fontSize'] = size

doc = []

for f in range(3):
    first = Paragraph('Why?', MainStyle(size=30))
    doc.append(first)

На выходе выдаёт три строки:
Why? # Маленькая
Why? # Большая
Why? # Снова большая (Как и должно быть во всех трёх итерациях)

То есть, все условия, записанные после текста "Why?" игнорируются в первой итерации и начинают работать начиная со второй.
Пришлось использовать лайфхак if not doc: doc.append(Paragraph(''), но хотелось бы знать причину ошибки))
ПС Мой первый вопрос здесь))
